# A special case of Karamata's inequality to solve one or more Olympiad inequality?

Tags: inequality, reference-request, contest-math, convexity-inequality, karamata-inequality

I was wondering if we can always use Karamata's inequality in Olympiad problem .For that I use a special case of Karamata's inequality :

> > If $a_1\geq a_2\geq a_3\geq\cdots\geq a_n$ and $b_1\geq b_2\geq b_3\geq\cdots\geq b_n$  are two sequences of positive real numbers which satisfy the following conditions:$$a_1\geq b_1,a_1a_2\geq b_1b_2,a_1a_2a_3\geq 
> >  b_1b_2b_3,a_1a_2\cdots a_n\geq b_1b_2\cdots b_n,$$ Then we have :
> >     $$a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n\geq b_1+b_2+b_3+\cdots+b_n$$

Like that this statement works rarely so the idea is to use $n>1$ a natural number such that :

> > If $a_1\geq a_2\geq a_3\geq\cdots\geq a_n$ and $b_1\geq b_2\geq b_3\geq\cdots\geq b_n$  are two sequences of positive real  numbers then we have  $\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_1}{n}\geq \frac{a_2}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_2}{n} \geq\cdots\geq \frac{a_n}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_n}{n}$and $b_1\geq b_2\geq b_3\geq\cdots\geq b_n$  satisfying the following conditions(call the conditions $C$):$$\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_1}{n}\geq b_1,(\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_1}{n})(\frac{a_2}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_2}{n})\geq b_1b_2,\cdots,(\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_1}{n})(\frac{a_2}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_2}{n})\cdots (\frac{a_n}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_n}{n})\geq b_1b_2\cdots b_n,$$ Then we have :
> >     $$a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n\geq b_1+b_2+b_3+\cdots+b_n$$

The advantage of this new version is: the values are closer and the majorization works better .

Now we have the following statement :

> > Let $x_i>0$ and $y_i>0$ $(i=1,\cdots,n)$ be real numbers then we have :
> >     $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(y_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(x_i)\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{y_i-x_i}{y_i}$$

So the conditions $C$ becomes $C_1$ :

$$\frac{\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_1}{n}-b_1}{\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_1}{n}}\geq0,\cdots,\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\frac{a_k}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_k}{n}-b_k}{\frac{a_k}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_k}{n}}\geq 0,$$

If we want to solve the polynomials of variable $n$ ,it becomes hard for $n\geq 4$ the case $n=3$ is a second degree inequality .

Useless to say we don't solve Nesbitt's inequality with this method but I have tried (and I don't find a counter-example where $n$ doesn't exist ) we can solve :
[Inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{18}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777075/inequality-sum-limits-cyc-fraca313a25b2-geq-fracabc18?noredirect=1&lq=1)

By example the last line of the majorization in the special case of Michael Rozenberg $(a,b,c)=(0.785,1.25,1.861)$ gives [$n\geq 5224$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%283.896*x%2F54%29%2F%28%280.785%5E3%29%2F%2813*0.785%5E2%2B5*1.25%5E2%29%2B3.896%28x-1%29%2F54%29%2B%283.896*x%2F54%29%2F%28%281.25%5E3%29%2F%2813*1.25%5E2%2B5*1.861%5E2%29%2B3.896*%28x-1%29%2F54%29%2B%283.896x%2F54%29%2F%28%281.861%5E3%29%2F%2813*1.861%5E2%2B5*0.785%5E2%29%2B3.896%28x-1%29%2F54%29%5Cle%203%20)

Futhermore I think we can solve the twin :[Olympiad Inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x^4}{8x^3+5y^3} \geqslant \frac{x+y+z}{13}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775572/olympiad-inequality-sum-limits-cyc-fracx48x35y3-geqslant-fracxy?noredirect=1&lq=1)

### My question :

What do you think about this method ? Is it already knew ?

Can someone show a hard inequality with that ?

Thanks a lot for your time and patience .

Edit :

### Sketch of proof :

We show for $a,b,c>0$ :
$$\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}+\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}+\frac{c^3}{13c^2+5a^2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{18}$$
If we apply the version with $n$ we get :

> > Let $a,b,c>0$ such that  $\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}\geq \frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}\geq \frac{c^3}{13c^2+5a^2}$  then  we have to show :$$\frac{\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{54}$$
> >     $$\Big(\frac{\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\Big)\geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{54^2}$$
> >     $$\Big(\frac{\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{\frac{c^3}{13c^2+5a^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\Big)\geq \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{54^3}$$

Or if we multiply by each denominator .

> > Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$ $a^3\geq b^3\geq c^3$ and $13a^2+5b^2\geq 13b^2+5c^2\geq 13c^2+5a^2$ then  we have to show :$$\frac{a^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13a^2+5b^2)}{54n}\geq \frac{13a^2+5b^2}{54}$$
> >     $$\Big(\frac{a^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13a^2+5b^2)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{b^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13b^2+5c^2)}{54n}\Big)\geq \frac{(13a^2+5b^2)(13b^2+5c^2)}{54^2}$$
> >     $$\Big(\frac{a^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13a^2+5b^2)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{b^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13b^2+5c^2)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{c^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13c^2+5a^2)}{54n}\Big)\geq \frac{(13a^2+5b^2)(13b^2+5c^2)(13c^2+5a^2)}{54^3}$$

### The first line :

We need to show :

$$54a^3\geq 13a^2+5b^2$$

Or : $$54a^3\geq 18a^2\geq 13a^2+5b^2$$

Or :$$a\geq \frac{1}{3}$$

### Second line :

We have to show using $C_1$:

$$\frac{\frac{-n}{54}}{\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}+\frac{n-1}{54}}+\frac{\frac{-n}{54}}{\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}+\frac{n-1}{54}}\geq -2$$

We put : 
$u=\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}$ and $v=\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}$

We have to show :

$$\frac{(108 uv + u n - 2 u + v n - 2 v - n/27 + 1/27)}{((54 u + n - 1) (54 v + n - 1))}\geq 0$$

Wich is obvious under the assumptions :

$$u>\frac{1}{54}, \frac{1}{54}<v<u, n>1 - 54 v$$

### Third line :

We have to show using $C_1$:

$$\frac{\frac{-n}{54}}{\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}+\frac{n-1}{54}}+\frac{\frac{-n}{54}}{\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}+\frac{n-1}{54}}+\frac{\frac{-n}{54}}{\frac{c^3}{13c^2+5a^2}+\frac{n-1}{54}}\geq -3$$

We put :

$p=\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}$ and $q=\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}$ and $r=\frac{c^3}{13c^2+5a^2}$

[As Wolfram alpha says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+-%28x%2F54%29%2F%28p%2B%28x-1%29%2F54%29%2B-%28x%2F54%29%2F%28q%2B%28x-1%29%2F54%29-%28x%2F54%29%2F%28r%2B%28x-1%29%2F54%29%3D-3) remains to show that the roots exists .Remains to calculate a limit when the denominator is zero.Furthermore  the expression under the root  is positive see [Inequality with a global minimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548722/inequality-with-a-global-minimum/3548733#3548733)

Comment: This is just Karamata applied to $\log a_i$ and $\log b_i$ for the convex function $t\mapsto e^t$. Rest of it sounds just packaging and grasping at straws.

Comment: @Macavity Maybe but you don't see that we cannot solve the inequality of Michael Rozenberg with the original statement and we can with the add of $n$ .

Comment: @The.old.boy   Denote the conditions after "So the conditions C becomes" by C1. Then C1 and C are not equivalent, only C1 implies C, not C implies C1, right?

Comment: @River Li Yes it is in this sense .It is a question about the sketch of proof ?

Comment: @RiverLi Do you think that my sketch of proof is valid ?

Comment: @The.old.boy   I think that you should make clear the connection between what you wrote and the inequality to be proved.

Comment: @RiverLi Is it clearer now? Thanks .

Comment: @The.old.boy   "Let $a, b, c > 0$ such that $\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}\geq \frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}\geq \frac{c^3}{13c^2+5a^2}$", do you mean you want to prove this case, and the other case is similar?

Comment: @RiverLi I mean that I want to prove this special case .For the other cases we need to take the reasoning at the beginning  each time .

Comment: @The.old.boy  So, did you come up with a complete proof for this inequality?

Comment: @RiverLi I don't have check the other cases . But have you something to tell about the existing sketch of proof (a counter-example by example)?

Comment: @The.old.boy   If you indeed prove the inequality with your argument, I would check it. Currently it is not enough.

Comment: @RiverLi I will open a bounty to understand what's wrong and how it could be work .If you have a counter-example it's the moment .