# About the conjecture $\frac{a^{4}}{133a^{3}+81b^{3}}+\frac{b^{3}}{133b^{3}+81c^{3}}+\frac{c^{4}}{133c^{3}+81a^{3}}-\frac{(a+\sqrt{b}+c)}{214}\ge 0$

Tags: inequality, jensen-inequality, buffalo-way

Hi working on [Prove that $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{214x^4}{133x^3 + 81y^3} \ge x + y + z$ for $x, y, z > 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709646/prove-that-sum-mathrmcyc-frac214x4133x3-81y3-ge-x-y-z-for/4459747#4459747) I found the following conjecture :

Let $0<a\leq b\leq1< 7/5\leq c $ then it seems we have :

$$\frac{a^{4}}{133a^{3}+81b^{3}}+\frac{b^{3}}{133b^{3}+81c^{3}}+\frac{c^{4}}{133c^{3}+81a^{3}}-\frac{\left(a+\sqrt{b}+c\right)}{214}\ge 0$$

For an attempt of the RiverLi's inequality see the first link . On my profile I show also a similar inequality but fails to get the hard case describe by RiverLi i mean $(a,b,c)=(43/66,1,121/84)$

It's a partial refinement of the strenghened HN_NH inequality .

Attempt :

As the function $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{133+81x^{6}}$ is convex on $(7/5,\infty)$ we use Jensen's inequality and the new problem is :

$$g(x,y,z)=\left(x^{2}+1\right)f\left(\frac{\left(\frac{z}{y}+xy\right)}{x^{2}+1}\right)+\frac{z^{8}}{133z^{6}+81x^{6}}-\frac{\left(x^{2}+y+z^{2}\right)}{214}\ge^? 0$$

We use Buffalo's way and for :

$$g\left(\frac{x}{x+y},1,\frac{7}{5}+x\right)\geq 0$$

Where all the coefficients are positives .

Question : How to (dis)prove it ?

> > > Thanks in advance .

Comment: I don't see why the inequality is of interest, where appearances of $a,c$ are symmetric and $b$ is not.  If it is of interest to you, I'd suggest rewriting it as a polynomial inequality.

Comment: @Hardmaths Now I think It's true have you an idea to show it more than an advice ?

Comment: I'm not your downvoter BTW.  It will take me some time to rewrite it as a polynomial and take derivatives, etc. to find a global minimum.  If you are interested, then I'll put it on my to-do list.

Answer (score -1):

Partial answer

Following the same path as in my attempt above for $x,y,z>0$ we have (I only set the numerator ):

$$g(1-1/(x+1),1-1/(y+1),7/5+x)=(40045166015625x³⁴ y¹³ + 520587158203125x³⁴ y¹² + 3123522949218750x³⁴ y¹¹ + 11452917480468750x³⁴ y¹⁰ + 28632293701171875x³⁴ y⁹ + 51538128662109375x³⁴ y⁸ + 68717504882812500x³⁴ y⁷ + 68717504882812500x³⁴ y⁶ + 51538128662109375x³⁴ y⁵ + 28632293701171875x³⁴ y⁴ + 11452917480468750x³⁴ y³ + 3123522949218750x³⁴ y² + 520587158203125x³⁴ y + 40045166015625x³⁴ + 1826059570312500x³³ y¹³ + 23258232421875000x³³ y¹² + 136906413574218750x³³ y¹¹ + 493180246582031250x³³ y¹⁰ + 1213128259277343750x³³ y⁹ + 2151915095214843750x³³ y⁸ + 2832218393554687500x³³ y⁷ + 2800502622070312500x³³ y⁶ + 2080554609375000000x³³ y⁵ + 1147053735351562500x³³ y⁴ + 456178513183593750x³³ y³ + 123931779785156250x³³ y² + 20615251464843750x³³ y + 1585788574218750x³³ + 39855994628906250x³² y¹³ + 497914811279296875x³² y¹² + 2878752300292968750x³² y¹¹ + 10200309512695312500x³² y¹⁰ + 24716541610107421875x³² y⁹ + 43255909472167968750x³² y⁸ + 56256303990234375000x³² y⁷ + 55056324190429687500x³² y⁶ + 40550548825195312500x³² y⁵ + 22201566756591796875x³² y⁴ + 8783514109863281250x³² y³ + 2378022205078125000x³² y² + 394913107177734375x³² y + 30382989257812500x³² + 554738751562500000x³¹ y¹³ + 6805766994433593750x³¹ y¹² + 38696342925585937500x³¹ y¹¹ + 135035195641699218750x³¹ y¹⁰ + 322716544044433593750x³¹ y⁹ + 557850980841503906250x³¹ y⁸ + 717679135506445312500x³¹ y⁷ + 695838526403906250000x³¹ y⁶ + 508517246731640625000x³¹ y⁵ + 276679596827636718750x³¹ y⁴ + 108952282849218750000x³¹ y³ + 29407864532519531250x³¹ y² + 4876978778613281250x³¹ y + 375338345800781250x³¹ + 5534809632333984375x³⁰ y¹³ + 66771113815019531250x³⁰ y¹² + 373849582703203125000x³⁰ y¹¹ + 1286477200445273437500x³⁰ y¹⁰ + 3036077728783593750000x³⁰ y⁹ + 5189816996175410156250x³⁰ y⁸ + 6611671075217343750000x³⁰ y⁷ + 6356865325391367187500x³⁰ y⁶ + 4613227380562324218750x³⁰ y⁵ + 2496086496235986328125x³⁰ y⁴ + 978886014403183593750x³⁰ y³ + 263522581578105468750x³⁰ y² + 43654473534111328125x³⁰ y + 3361351194931640625x³⁰ + 42188982587507812500x²⁹ y¹³ + 501176935407621093750x²⁹ y¹² + 2767020831324632812500x²⁹ y¹¹ + 9402013783185925781250x²⁹ y¹⁰ + 21938723546076386718750x²⁹ y⁹ + 37127534164685542968750x²⁹ y⁸ + 46887793468801101562500x²⁹ y⁷ + 44745739267232742187500x²⁹ y⁶ + 32272309551444820312500x²⁹ y⁵ + 17376522423078339843750x²⁹ y⁴ + 6790237290122449218750x²⁹ y³ + 1823926114642992187500x²⁹ y² + 301900157135648437500x²⁹ y + 23261139259382812500x²⁹ + 255697648596977343750x²⁸ y¹³ + 2995469730161363671875x²⁸ y¹² + 16331139715440283593750x²⁸ y¹¹ + 54867268774912035937500x²⁸ y¹⁰ + 126744631423035451171875x²⁸ y⁹ + 212599118777714528906250x²⁸ y⁸ + 266429563297670981250000x²⁸ y⁷ + 252601074895037371875000x²⁸ y⁶ + 181207615645362150000000x²⁸ y⁵ + 97157806624480324218750x²⁸ y⁴ + 37851486896621067187500x²⁸ y³ + 10148892072948435937500x²⁸ y² + 1678963677566814843750x²⁸ y + 129467429039664843750x²⁸ + 1266258566529480937500x²⁷ y¹³ + 14651125399013647500000x²⁷ y¹² + 78992024803917020156250x²⁷ y¹¹ + 262759851868022644218750x²⁷ y¹⁰ + 601654119189616764843750x²⁷ y⁹ + 1001437198537190736093750x²⁷ y⁸ + 1246662980495228477812500x²⁷ y⁷ + 1175323172135194240312500x²⁷ y⁶ + 839270777882275440000000x²⁷ y⁵ + 448391795098194850781250x²⁷ y⁴ + 174251551829851880156250x²⁷ y³ + 46655314173565025625000x²⁷ y² + 7716339044075638125000x²⁷ y + 595594600313557500000x²⁷ + 5225362917899062078125x²⁶ y¹³ + 59807818296107216312500x²⁶ y¹² + 319352139487160276156250x²⁶ y¹¹ + 1053214271399838515437500x²⁶ y¹⁰ + 2393423617389092012421875x²⁶ y⁹ + 3957619247806346498062500x²⁶ y⁸ + 4898967556776161692312500x²⁶ y⁷ + 4596807897941562619187500x²⁶ y⁶ + 3269938137513122210484375x²⁶ y⁵ + 1741929620039365395234375x²⁶ y⁴ + 675601773485826219187500x²⁶ y³ + 180708115063615417406250x²⁶ y² + 29887910887337768812500x²⁶ y + 2309527975516753640625x²⁶ + 18234242193379760043750x²⁵ y¹³ + 206784836133354011600000x²⁵ y¹² + 1095150668495052606600000x²⁵ y¹¹ + 3585776496917642764668750x²⁵ y¹⁰ + 8097295967308721555968750x²⁵ y⁹ + 13316150749842980093493750x²⁵ y⁸ + 16406977996409802126825000x²⁵ y⁷ + 15335766337620900227075000x²⁵ y⁶ + 10875669811904481879993750x²⁵ y⁵ + 5780415737558941621593750x²⁵ y⁴ + 2238641102876235584231250x²⁵ y³ + 598418941238789131631250x²⁵ y² + 99003381024309060318750x²⁵ y + 7660072372245817668750x²⁵ + 54415784144139721993125x²⁴ y¹³ + 612424765105953151176250x²⁴ y¹² + 3221790092392527650276250x²⁴ y¹¹ + 10487154112125552558408750x²⁴ y¹⁰ + 23561454290899791022896875x²⁴ y⁹ + 38578482409075402584058125x²⁴ y⁸ + 47358906004383564088702500x²⁴ y⁷ + 44134543533491632949515000x²⁴ y⁶ + 31226237997180113310339375x²⁴ y⁵ + 16569385586491378382662500x²⁴ y⁴ + 6410877411370979438471250x²⁴ y³ + 1713331736526766274088750x²⁴ y² + 283615800017479926035625x²⁴ y + 21975253221164629899375x²⁴ + 140097881214789702511500x²³ y¹³ + 1567371736550954172275750x²³ y¹² + 8202615803291226927645750x²³ y¹¹ + 26579618936391307298911500x²³ y¹⁰ + 59485165000733361051197500x²³ y⁹ + 97079934296356529339613000x²³ y⁸ + 118853811594708847846486500x²³ y⁷ + 110524546027469584032194000x²³ y⁶ + 78074219310847582454095500x²³ y⁵ + 41385185274639881553322500x²³ y⁴ + 16005095772421506660414000x²³ y³ + 4278107863064557453617000x²³ y² + 708761840677522280329500x²³ y + 55003174290444947746500x²³ + 313318852960515488970525x²² y¹³ + 3490287275733529059250825x²² y¹² + 18197980174820034291995700x²² y¹¹ + 58780886264670797506005900x²² y¹⁰ + 131199852171070384697636000x²² y⁹ + 213647925569779031191468800x²² y⁸ + 261109881323045969545338900x²² y⁷ + 242493378285198203299102900x²² y⁶ + 171146654129886622420678425x²² y⁵ + 90681382586799286449982875x²² y⁴ + 35070860963926195463482650x²² y³ + 9379344423863452856416200x²² y² + 1555583890383688259116575x²² y + 120927597139421767881900x²² + 611951535728382657703590x²¹ y¹³ + 6799091277365062422364520x²¹ y¹² + 35370274550459193777257670x²¹ y¹¹ + 114036497707358276752971540x²¹ y¹⁰ + 254152432288737801351613600x²¹ y⁹ + 413394365601616849575101580x²¹ y⁸ + 504821358031696596173603640x²¹ y⁷ + 468599208611021828625237740x²¹ y⁶ + 330670860887502610446307680x²¹ y⁵ + 175232709319285125933314850x²¹ y⁴ + 67805793489456649350680490x²¹ y³ + 18150351098370620999109120x²¹ y² + 3014309722209510783653820x²¹ y + 234758662497866982721140x²¹ + 1048133534952063773842299x²⁰ y¹³ + 11634164330726559702967617x²⁰ y¹² + 60476843643458446448981442x²⁰ y¹¹ + 194875885541475478897250904x²⁰ y¹⁰ + 434182063908027040275171435x²⁰ y⁹ + 706157505752422530466672938x²⁰ y⁸ + 862432171624129229834932044x²⁰ y⁷ + 800804820029752660794450924x²⁰ y⁶ + 565389625676182897318041168x²⁰ y⁵ + 299839500458903105278236810x²⁰ y⁴ + 116136272438802570321746514x²⁰ y³ + 31126762882992015068237802x²⁰ y² + 5177552900249880283795857x²⁰ y + 404029656363458242834389x²⁰ + 1579158339821572973237370x¹⁹ y¹³ + 17540897384652218805540630x¹⁹ y¹² + 91244883957704558272872540x¹⁹ y¹¹ + 294243582571768781060791680x¹⁹ y¹⁰ + 656128633614593520101172900x¹⁹ y⁹ + 1068137531049171460958605440x¹⁹ y⁸ + 1305861336231859636095049560x¹⁹ y⁷ + 1213897847157749841971826180x¹⁹ y⁶ + 858076566984812881589896710x¹⁹ y⁵ + 455655230565596822764116900x¹⁹ y⁴ + 176743117740819148266316320x¹⁹ y³ + 47446914961124537628300930x¹⁹ y² + 7906568908525401496348890x¹⁹ y + 618273034189374358837530x¹⁹ + 2097421252297725961342845x¹⁸ y¹³ + 23352623823825914250030615x¹⁸ y¹² + 121737872031754556692797030x¹⁸ y¹¹ + 393381816010660407624612660x¹⁸ y¹⁰ + 878950437117383300109774075x¹⁸ y⁹ + 1433690453110373516546302140x¹⁸ y⁸ + 1756157567081499984408857280x¹⁸ y⁷ + 1635583664149471454833791360x¹⁸ y⁶ + 1158326139049262100382315320x¹⁸ y⁵ + 616245308729328671844045075x¹⁸ y⁴ + 239487201389382847932281670x¹⁸ y³ + 64416106252977985077505290x¹⁸ y² + 10756262358790271444252205x¹⁸ y + 842947937555677420177035x¹⁸ + 2459086325687722147292250x¹⁷ y¹³ + 27488635486881897902747820x¹⁷ y¹² + 143813387081618327644913430x¹⁷ y¹¹ + 466265156994686229551986860x¹⁷ y¹⁰ + 1045073053505228298207657600x¹⁷ y⁹ + 1709743362900046285114818000x¹⁷ y⁸ + 2100221676217060524943609140x¹⁷ y⁷ + 1961262361927737258339940260x¹⁷ y⁶ + 1392501100048914937381006770x¹⁷ y⁵ + 742625665324395020886576600x¹⁷ y⁴ + 289276089968289604804062750x¹⁷ y³ + 77985611248130153217148320x¹⁷ y² + 13051517699509333090192080x¹⁷ y + 1025146117577928989891160x¹⁷ + 2546375308264123270438050x¹⁶ y¹³ + 28623364948773022517076330x¹⁶ y¹² + 150499769217483515255884845x¹⁶ y¹¹ + 490188937726845789185223315x¹⁶ y¹⁰ + 1103398501321287086404241025x¹⁶ y⁹ + 1812372637342844421148950225x¹⁶ y⁸ + 2234565568072807008015124035x¹⁶ y⁷ + 2093915807937780025656637665x¹⁶ y⁶ + 1491438538227690164333443455x¹⁶ y⁵ + 797750850121231184733028275x¹⁶ y⁴ + 311610088264002380427959550x¹⁶ y³ + 84225252236181330733626330x¹⁶ y² + 14130473675355447448334445x¹⁶ y + 1112499259048040228539515x¹⁶ + 2328230776882835950351236x¹⁵ y¹³ + 26357862615949257922937958x¹⁵ y¹² + 139474417576794286144770918x¹⁵ y¹¹ + 456939386744905350242704116x¹⁵ y¹⁰ + 1034120310222320717108314440x¹⁵ y⁹ + 1707076017696368466086937732x¹⁵ y⁸ + 2114432405760518685533799756x¹⁵ y⁷ + 1989702859508842200042202296x¹⁵ y⁶ + 1422666894277860869261801322x¹⁵ y⁵ + 763635390531261424486012440x¹⁵ y⁴ + 299237953902314044512711996x¹⁵ y³ + 81116993122689982907604798x¹⁵ y² + 13645140957011349019998378x¹⁵ y + 1076878906028304415223706x¹⁵ + 1877745108249305372676285x¹⁴ y¹³ + 21440892457920052974391540x¹⁴ y¹² + 114335255369358078404532270x¹⁴ y¹¹ + 377237923054736617022481465x¹⁴ y¹⁰ + 859324501977170184036987575x¹⁴ y⁹ + 1427056509375676009094768295x¹⁴ y⁸ + 1777303639077220473577234980x¹⁴ y⁷ + 1680803969726557249060602715x¹⁴ y⁶ + 1207209994610104146800556855x¹⁴ y⁵ + 650606724459229375734066450x¹⁴ y⁴ + 255869273236451030934330510x¹⁴ y³ + 69584119547634422121675690x¹⁴ y² + 11738378228872079868343695x¹⁴ y + 928678500272363207769765x¹⁴ + 1333362752722859681737710x¹³ y¹³ + 15376956144197446480818620x¹³ y¹² + 82741324795984092332060490x¹³ y¹¹ + 275267149730852534598773280x¹³ y¹⁰ + 631843145746311312135009850x¹³ y⁹ + 1056652164015038186639284020x¹³ y⁸ + 1324397086769806780295727390x¹³ y⁷ + 1259705692984535812646185880x¹³ y⁶ + 909428129076272793216276060x¹³ y⁵ + 492366940170396465498197850x¹³ y⁴ + 194419055118371938912760310x¹³ y³ + 53058858891378242332691520x¹³ y² + 8977683955299127039552140x¹³ y + 712046302151105145297780x¹³ + 831322488700159839694800x¹² y¹³ + 9694880335278581646433735x¹² y¹² + 52703734458413995874140065x¹² y¹¹ + 177004270638911646080162880x¹² y¹⁰ + 409857985055562199634919800x¹² y⁹ + 690930283529929678806611850x¹² y⁸ + 872321017919582693464531845x¹² y⁷ + 835142887645365345711662080x¹² y⁶ + 606427724438114009757568785x¹² y⁵ + 330002756024363713236911175x¹² y⁴ + 130887839139501841235259300x¹² y³ + 35857037623915033107502860x¹² y² + 6086440044863651976952140x¹² y + 483958771623029537922780x¹² + 453399524422568056312560x¹¹ y¹³ + 5352507748292708039737470x¹¹ y¹² + 29430219097959252448946490x¹¹ y¹¹ + 99894968667898151871000780x¹¹ y¹⁰ + 233597074390536535965155100x¹¹ y⁹ + 397365115197476612678148720x¹¹ y⁸ + 505806325022696312953181340x¹¹ y⁷ + 487805152669882736105303880x¹¹ y⁶ + 356511653646064470603936810x¹¹ y⁵ + 195104180300144969843715600x¹¹ y⁴ + 77761197376854258930173910x¹¹ y³ + 21390594246196651386744120x¹¹ y² + 3643063560305859498844140x¹¹ y + 290418639234011806899780x¹¹ + 215265921283767496854789x¹⁰ y¹³ + 2574480163216162249629672x¹⁰ y¹² + 14331572013959983452211227x¹⁰ y¹¹ + 49218159549337243922841174x¹⁰ y¹⁰ + 116358705319222526328094710x¹⁰ y⁹ + 199936342768933162812058443x¹⁰ y⁸ + 256828836012834514206464379x¹⁰ y⁷ + 249710141378253941588501844x¹⁰ y⁶ + 183810231061547866479280458x¹⁰ y⁵ + 101218088998185003832233960x¹⁰ y⁴ + 40555983904018958868022404x¹⁰ y³ + 11205454734441168757064082x¹⁰ y² + 1915138281189371994392742x¹⁰ y + 153066586866136247757159x¹⁰ + 88423858933430078672460x⁹ y¹³ + 1071732483444386075143440x⁹ y¹² + 6045089191112440950364170x⁹ y¹¹ + 21025869377686687280719890x⁹ y¹⁰ + 50309032144411111377730200x⁹ y⁹ + 87410772162692117052466770x⁹ y⁸ + 113420307493988128230522030x⁹ y⁷ + 111269817588187144110962640x⁹ y⁶ + 82551238448706065780998830x⁹ y⁵ + 45767379165628763181618450x⁹ y⁴ + 18443519222900709077082810x⁹ y³ + 5119944412019953735354590x⁹ y² + 878284012433377293115470x⁹ y + 70379612778728620970190x⁹ + 31180309480216971995760x⁸ y¹³ + 382927651767328061761395x⁸ y¹² + 2189577835564159017830265x⁸ y¹¹ + 7719970563105801129472455x⁸ y¹⁰ + 18714675838404808283421225x⁸ y⁹ + 32914706445335101723126245x⁸ y⁸ + 43183697377039420559116815x⁸ y⁷ + 42783750023255869290415305x⁸ y⁶ + 32015235141690635874788910x⁸ y⁵ + 17880967670787327975140475x⁸ y⁴ + 7250480646888731265497610x⁸ y³ + 2022885969769826384900670x⁸ y² + 348348816569337219039915x⁸ y + 27987720163739822967705x⁸ + 9346236715607090159700x⁷ y¹³ + 116183967007219537741560x⁷ y¹² + 673503531049253215869390x⁷ y¹¹ + 2408795182152805353756030x⁷ y¹⁰ + 5922085576381654621038300x⁷ y⁹ + 10554549182529771525753150x⁷ y⁸ + 14015873666236879162497870x⁷ y⁷ + 14036146097966618402193480x⁷ y⁶ + 10602098802372495793074210x⁷ y⁵ + 5968951703794330749026550x⁷ y⁴ + 2436507056476588049885700x⁷ y³ + 683435142410606906173560x⁷ y² + 118165516381755379194840x⁷ y + 9519118805971387075680x⁷ + 2351698051354640247330x⁶ y¹³ + 29524876127590888291905x⁶ y¹² + 173405925134731381302000x⁶ y¹¹ + 629359647781043955796650x⁶ y¹⁰ + 1570635534540686617390275x⁶ y⁹ + 2839681119274194235976460x⁶ y⁸ + 3820906827341391943214010x⁶ y⁷ + 3871514096368104630740850x⁶ y⁶ + 2954232465428140710877350x⁶ y⁵ + 1677675545772920898532650x⁶ y⁴ + 689744557895675111708130x⁶ y³ + 194577356314331965860480x⁶ y² + 33784559385552464143725x⁶ y + 2728926634437183136950x⁶ + 488611800481236146316x⁵ y¹³ + 6170627716393551793438x⁵ y¹² + 36658975913103248497968x⁵ y¹¹ + 135006705297638866354866x⁵ y¹⁰ + 342261808923155643694340x⁵ y⁹ + 628420309064711619012942x⁵ y⁸ + 857729581213743167375166x⁵ y⁷ + 880228964296716890925496x⁵ y⁶ + 679135685618919464002872x⁵ y⁵ + 389296747617350208421590x⁵ y⁴ + 161288127753737671228626x⁵ y³ + 45776194347092548686228x⁵ y² + 7983374423886411830028x⁵ y + 646617307123157580756x⁵ + 81957272467952280420x⁴ y¹³ + 1034454615487691461280x⁴ y¹² + 6196830752860657738815x⁴ y¹¹ + 23138006594732103676980x⁴ y¹⁰ + 59616114233712745962400x⁴ y⁹ + 111277029026071890444540x⁴ y⁸ + 154247539667853518439735x⁴ y⁷ + 160498006080032921832980x⁴ y⁶ + 125323721692183490757435x⁴ y⁵ + 72567960512196470559525x⁴ y⁴ + 30314840808193153599870x⁴ y³ + 8659575056015678554830x⁴ y² + 1517262695326356108165x⁴ y + 123235238061118356705x⁴ + 10735809923486027520x³ y¹³ + 134130086852198596390x³ y¹² + 805832556970019829180x³ y¹¹ + 3044469685212417094710x³ y¹⁰ + 7972506450483211887950x³ y⁹ + 15142583466099506616990x³ y⁸ + 21343027748941582004580x³ y⁷ + 22543710950132748133660x³ y⁶ + 17833305082505657083920x³ y⁵ + 10439623516364826471450x³ y⁴ + 4399991085888366408720x³ y³ + 1265558867503278146190x³ y² + 222828501600055871730x³ y + 18150664147404054210x³ + 1040028548809761000x² y¹³ + 12690983048757006070x² y¹² + 75810122240092113930x² y¹¹ + 288686991496914785985x² y¹⁰ + 767776497308464240100x² y⁹ + 1485028916849467917375x² y⁸ + 2130992964993429129390x² y⁷ + 2287831004890305530635x² y⁶ + 1835501661780886420020x² y⁵ + 1087267419866162355975x² y⁴ + 462649870132608721500x² y³ + 134052583269855797820x² y² + 23725055888188997580x² y + 1938301471015989660x² + 67056517298985480x y¹³ + 785916232272105620x y¹² + 4607916355858328310x y¹¹ + 17567362202132523270x y¹⁰ + 47354176666011262600x y⁹ + 93309972802264487010x y⁸ + 136495682676052053690x y⁷ + 149154801751502175020x y⁶ + 121513528047873630690x y⁵ + 72905881267063196100x y⁴ + 31343695631235323280x y³ + 9153548703229826070x y² + 1628921711563597710x y + 133494647428868670x + 2187485938334214y¹³ + 24185234693082232y¹² + 136703386522543092y¹¹ + 516017264952741279y¹⁰ + 1403909072528077010y⁹ + 2817467826702921168y⁸ + 4206538158178634124y⁷ + 4685750926055899399y⁶ + 3881657060370850068y⁵ + 2361505401797985135y⁴ + 1026613863578199204y³ + 302352427210146642y² + 54119875877100432y + 4449821580962289) $$

Comment: It works also with 4/3 instead of 7/5.

Comment: Cheating : $b=1$ and you are left with a polynomial of degree $107$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What you are 107 years old ?:-)

Comment: A bit older. Didn't you know it ? Back to serious : I suggest you do not write such an answer. It does not bring anything to the problem (IMHO at least). Cheers :-)